# How to order a list of objects (mix cocktail) in scala

Tags: scala

I'm a little confused with lists ordering in Scala.

I want to indicate how a list should be mixed. For example I have a list of numbers. These numbers have a letter. I want to order these numbers by a pattern of letters.

```
val numbers = List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "b"), (6, "a"), (7, "a"))
// order pattern
val cocktail = List("a", "b", "a", "b") 
// Expected output: 1, 2, 3, 5 

val cocktail2 = List("a", "a", "a", "b") 
// Expected output: 1, 3, 4, 2
```

Please any suggest?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the fast replies. all is working now!

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I've tried the two examples and work perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Davidtor Welcome to StackOverflow – if one of the answers solved your issue, you should check that answer.  When you gain more reputation, you would also upvote the answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
def orderWithPattern(list : List[(Int, String)], pattern: List[String]) : List[Int] = {
  val start = (list, List[Int]())
  // fold over the pattern list and try to find the letters in the list
  pattern.foldLeft(start) { case ((list, numbers), elem) => 
    list.indexWhere(_._2 == elem) match {
      case -1 => 
        // letter in pattern not found
        (list, numbers)
      case index =>
        // letter in pattern found
        // => remove from list and add to currently (reversed) ordered numbers
        val (begin, (n, letter) :: end) = list.splitAt(index)
        (begin ::: end, n :: numbers)
     }   
  }._2.reverse // return reversed numbers
}
```

Which can be used as :

```
scala> orderWithPattern(numbers, cocktail)
res14: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5)

scala> orderWithPattern(numbers, List("a", "a", "c", "d", "b"))
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object ListOrdering extends App {

  val numbers = List((1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "a"), (4, "a"), (5, "b"), (6, "a"), (7, "a"))
  val cocktail = List("a", "b", "a", "b")
  val cocktail2 = List("a", "a", "a", "b")

  def mix[T, S](order: List[S], ss: List[(T, S)]): List[T] = {
    def loop(acc: List[T], order: List[S], ls: List[(T, S)]): List[T] = order match {
      case Nil => acc
      case x :: xs =>
        val firstFound = ls.find(_._2 == x).get    //this can throw Exception! You must have correct pattern!
        val newLs = ls.filter(_ != firstFound)
        loop(acc :+ firstFound._1, xs, newLs)
    }
    loop(Nil, order, ss)
  }

  println(mix(cocktail, numbers))
  println(mix(cocktail2, numbers))

}
```

Using type parameters T,S you can generalize mix function to work on different types. Also you didn't mentioned what to do in case of incorrect pattern, so this code will just throw an NoSuchElementException.